# Bash Scripting - Using Entry immediately after certain phrase

Tags: bash, scripting

In my project, addgpg-apt (https://launchpad.net/addgpg-apt), I'd like to be able to have input sent into the program.  From that input, say...
`Unable to verify signatures in PPA.  Check that this is fixed: NO_PUBKEY <PGPkeyID>`
... how can I, using basic Bash, grep, etc. get that `<PGPkeyID>` from the string and ignore everything else in the string?  (Note that these errors are generated by `apt-get`/`apt`, and as such the end of the string is always `NO_PUBKEY <PGPkeyID>`)

In Java, this could be done with substring, and grab only that PGPkeyID based on the location of the phrase `NO_PUBKEY`, but I want this to be done in Bash only, so any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Piping to `grep -o "NO_PUBKEY <.*>" | sed -e 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/'`

will yield you:

`PGPkeyID`

---

**Update**

Assuming your input is like this:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAFE0123DEADBEEF
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0123DEADBEEFCAFE
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DEADBEEFCAFE0123
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BEEFCAFE0123DEAD
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAFE0123DEADBEEF
```

The following command will extract the keys:

```
grep -o 'PUBKEY [A-F0-9]\{16\}' | cut -f2 -d" " | sort -u
```

Like this:

```
0123DEADBEEFCAFE
BEEFCAFE0123DEAD
CAFE0123DEADBEEF
DEADBEEFCAFE0123
```

Comment: +1 You can put the grep functionality inside the sed script to save on pipes: `sed -e '/NO_PUBKEY <.*>/ s/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/'`. However if the OP actually wants "<PGPkeyID>" at the end of the string, then `grep -o '<[^>]\+>$'` suffices.

Comment: @MattH And assuming i have, say, 15 lines similar to that one, can I pipe those 15 lines through this, or should I pipe it through this and other items?

Comment: @glennjackman yeah, the PGPkeyID is needed only for the script... it goes and manually fetches from the keyservers the specified PGPkeyID, hence why that is the only required return.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: If you had a bunch of out put with occasionally lines matching what you've suggested. I'd suggest you filter the output with `sort -u` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: This hasnt worked, for some reason.  It doesn't separate out the actual keys.  And just a note, the <PGPkeyID> is a placeholder, there's really only a Hexadecimal string for where <PGPkeyID> is.

Comment: Post an actual sample then, everyone answering has assumed what you wanted was between angle-brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in pure shell without spawning a process:

```
cat << EOF > file
...
Unable to verify signatures in PPA. Check that this is fixed: NO_PUBKEY <PGPkeyID1>
...
Unable to verify signatures in PPA. Check that this is fixed: NO_PUBKEY <PGPkeyID2>
...
EOF

cat file | while read line; do
  if [[ $line == *\ NO_PUBKEY\ * ]]
  then
    echo ${line#* NO_PUBKEY }
  fi
done
```